# Are there challenge dungeons on iOS remake of Final Fantasy IV: The After Years?

Tags: final-fantasy-4

I didn't seem to find any of the challenge dungeons yet... Are they even in game?

I finished Ceodore, Palom's and Porom's story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. On the iOS version various things are missing. This includes the challenge dungeons. Other things that are missing are the extensive dungeon in the final chapter and Proto-Babil.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no challenge dungeon. The entrance is not there on Ceodore's story. There is no Namingway changing his name to Challengingway.

Comment: I didn't see anything on Palom's and Porom's story either. It's odd that no one has said anything about it...

Answer (score 0):

Not from what I've seen unfortunately. Just finished the Lunarian mission and there's no namingway dude there either.